# JavaScript - Adding the totals in Array with same index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have moved on to learning about looping over arrays and hit a hurdle - did try researching but I think I am probably not describing  properly...

I have managed to total each line in the array.
I did create another variable called total but not sure I needed that...

I get the output below, which all seem to occupy index 0 - think I have confused myself here :)

```
22
14
201
```

Now I want to add these values. -Any pointers would be most welcome.

```js
function addArray(arr) {
  let total = [];

  let totalNumber = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    totalNumber += arr[i];
  }
  total.push(totalNumber);

  console.log(total[0])
  return totalNumber;
}

addArray([17, 2, 3])
addArray([2, 8, 2, 2])
addArray([150, 50, 1])
```

Comment: What are you trying to do / what is your expected result?

Comment: I want to add the totals 22,14 and 201

Comment: Do you know if you need to use separate function calls (you're using three here), or can you use one, and pass all of the arrays in like so: `addArray([[17, 2, 3], [2, 8, 2, 2], [150, 50, 1]])`?

Comment: Thanks - I did not realise that I could do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using three separate function calls, I suggest you use one, and pass through a 2d array (an array that contains other arrays):

```
addArrays([[17, 2, 3], [2, 8, 2, 2], [150, 50, 1]])
```

You can now create two separate functions. The first function is responsible for summing the numbers in a nested array (eg: `[17, 2, 3]` gives `22`), and another for looping over each array you want to sum, and adding that to a total. You have already made the first function (although, as you mentioned, the `total` variable that stores an array isn't needed, so this can be removed for this approach)

```
function sumArray(arr) {
  let totalNumber = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    totalNumber += arr[i];
  }
  return totalNumber;
}
```

The next step is to create a second function, that will loop through an array of arrays (so each element within your array is an array itself):

```js
function sumArray(arr) {
  let totalNumber = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    totalNumber += arr[i];
  }
  return totalNumber;
}

function addArrays(arrays) {
  let totalNumber = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    let currentArray = arrays[i];
    totalNumber += sumArray(currentArray); // sum the current array values, and add it to the total 
  }
  return totalNumber;
}

console.log(addArrays([[17, 2, 3], [2, 8, 2, 2], [150, 50, 1]])); // 237
```

The above can be written by using nested loops, but using functions to decompose your logic can help with clarity. You can use separate function calls though if you use a closure (ie: create a total sum in your function and return a function that is responsible for adding to that total). If you're a beginner, I suggest the first approach as it's more straightforward:

```js
function createAdder() {
  let runningTotal = 0;
  return function(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      runningTotal += arr[i];
    }
    return runningTotal;
  }
}
const addArray = createAdder();
addArray([17, 2, 3])
addArray([2, 8, 2, 2])
console.log(addArray([150, 50, 1]));
```

Finally, you can use array methods, such as `.reduce()` to make your code more concise. Using `.reduce()` hides an internal loop behind a method call, which allow you to "reduce" the values in your array into another/transformed value (in this case, your sum):

```js
function addArrays(arrays) {
  return arrays.reduce(
    (totalSum, arr) => totalSum + arr.reduce((arrSum, num) => arrSum + num, 0)
  , 0);
}

console.log(addArrays([[17, 2, 3], [2, 8, 2, 2], [150, 50, 1]])); // 237
```

Comment: Thanks Nick -  Totally Awesome your examples have actually allowed me to not only see where I went wrong, but helped me to understand the first two examples- I had an Aha moment, regarding calling functions from your examples - Thank you!!  I think I will tackle .reduce when I have more than a few weeks of learning under my belt :)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you create `total` inside your `function`, so it is always recreated when the `function` is being called and the result is pushed to it's 0 index. Fix:

```js
    function addArray(arr) {
    
      let totalNumber = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        totalNumber += arr[i];
      }
    
      return totalNumber;
    }
    
    let total = [];
    total.push(addArray([17, 2, 3]));
    total.push(addArray([2, 8, 2, 2]));
    total.push(addArray([150, 50, 1]));
    
    console.log(total);
```

Comment: Thank you - this makes sense now :)